# Every time on scanning bluetooth devices gives CBCentralManagerStateUnknown?

Tags: core-bluetooth

First time I am using coreBluetooth.
Here is my implementation is there any thing wrong in it.

```
@synthesize CM,activePeripheral;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CM = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (int) scanForPeripherals
{

    if (self.CM.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth is %s",[self centralManagerStateToString:self.CM.state]);
        return -1;
    }

    [self.CM scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]] options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES}];
    return 0;
}

- (const char *) centralManagerStateToString: (int)state
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
            return "State unknown (CBCentralManagerStateUnknown)";
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
            return "State resetting (CBCentralManagerStateUnknown)";
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            return "State BLE unsupported (CBCentralManagerStateResetting)";
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            return "State unauthorized (CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized)";
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            return "State BLE powered off (CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff)";
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            return "State powered up and ready (CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)";
        default:
            return "State unknown";
    }

    return "Unknown state";
}


- (void) connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    printf("Connecting to peripheral with UUID : %s\r\n",[self UUIDToString:peripheral.UUID]);

    self.activePeripheral = peripheral;
    self.activePeripheral.delegate = self;
    [self.CM connectPeripheral:self.activePeripheral options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey]];
}


-(const char *) UUIDToString:(CFUUIDRef)UUID
{
    if (!UUID)
        return "NULL";

    CFStringRef s = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, UUID);
    return CFStringGetCStringPtr(s, 0);
}


#pragma mark -Central manager delegate method

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

    NSLog(@"hits it");
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    isOn=YES;
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Received periferal :%@",peripheral);
    NSLog(@"Ad data :%@",advertisementData);

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Connected peripheral %@",peripheral);
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error occured :%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)scanDevices:(id)sender {
     if (isOn) {
       [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
       [self scanForPeripherals];
    }
}
```

Every time it gives log

```
 CoreBluetooth is State unknown (CBCentralManagerStateUnknown)
```

**update to question**

After suggestion given by @Michael Dautermann , I come to know that my centralManagerDidUpdateState delegate method is not hitting.I dunno why this is happening.If anybody finds the reason please notify me.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreBluetooth is simply in the process of starting up.

You need this delegate method to hit first:

```
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState: (CBCentralManager *) central;
```

And once it does, *then* you can start scanning for peripherals.

Comment: is it possible , it is not supported in iPhone 4

Comment: I am running latest ios 6.1.3 with iphone4.

Comment: iPhone 4 doesn't have BLE. Only starting from 4S, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After few days, I checked out the initialization of CentralManager and I come to know that init method on firstViewController never called.I checked out by printing log in init method.

```
- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"hello init");
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CM = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   CM = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    isOn=NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

So , I initialize the central manager in viewDidLoad and now it is initialized and centralManagerDidUpdateState finally called.Now printing `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` and that's not the issue because iPhone 4 doesn't support it.Thanks to michael help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call `scanDevices`? I think you're calling it too early. You should call it inside `centralManagerDidUpdateState`.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

    NSLog(@"hits it");
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [self scanDevices]:
    }

    isOn=YES;
}
```

Comment: As below answer is saying that I should call after centralManagerDidUpdateState I called it after that but if centralManagerDidUpdateState is not calling then what can I do?

Comment: centralManagerDidUpdateState is called automatically if the bluetooth is on.

Comment: It will also call when bluetooth is off

Comment: self.CM.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn Won't be true unless bluetooth is turned on. But apparently your problem is that you're using iPhone 4 that doesn't have Bluetooth v4.

Comment: but it should print NSLog(@"hits it"); if centralManagerDidUpdateState is calling.

Comment: on button action I am calling - (IBAction)scanDevices:(id)sender

Comment: I know I have read some docs and I come to know it will not work in iphone 4 but centralManagerDidUpdateState method must call.